# Get file size of posted file does not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending a file using ajax to a PHP file. All things go OK but the size.

the jquery :

```
<script>
$('#submitshout').click(function () {
    $('.shoutinputhover').show();
    var formDatashout = new FormData($('#shoutform')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "../pages/sn/ajax/submitshout.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formDatashout,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
            if (msg == 'update') {
                addshout();
            }
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
   });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="shoutform" >
    <textarea  class="ordinaryinput" style="width: 100%;height: 60px" id="shouttxtarea" name="shouttxtarea"></textarea>
    <div class="shoutaddimage">
    <input type="file" name="shoutaddimageer"  id="shoutaddimageer"  style="width: 100%"   >
    </div>
    </form>
```

and PHP file:

```
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); 

require '../../../elements/config.php' ;

// get image
die($_FILES["shoutaddimageer"]["size"]);
```

If I place **name** or **type** instead of size in above php code it will return file type or file name accurately but it does not work with size and it returns nothing!!!!

Since I can get file type and file name it means that sending form is going ok . but whats wrong with the size ??

Answer (score 0):

If your file upload is aborted for any reason then have no size.
Check what will return: `$_FILES['shoutaddimageer']['error']`
Here is a list of errors: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: No,it is not aborted. it get uploaded and the only thing that i can not get in this case is size and other things go flawlessly.